# Android, landscape orientation?

Tags: android

I created one application. In this application is only in landscape mode. I open the application in device it's open in landscape mode but when the device is lock then when I open lock then application is portrait mode after some time the app in landscape mode.
I already defined in AndroidManifest.xml file android:screenOrientation="landscape" in all activity. I want set only landscape mode. How to do this. Help me.

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml here?

Comment: Are you sure android:screenOrientation="landscape" in all activity ?

Comment: yes i defined in all activity.

Comment: your All layout .xml file in layout-land  folder>?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `layout` folder to `layout-land` and in your manifest.xml file, under application tab, check your activity's screen orientation to be landscape. If these are checked, it shouldn't have a problem.